# View File Permissions In Windows 7 Like Linux OS

Tags: linux, windows

is there a way to view the file permissions for a file in a Windows that will give the same output like as Linux machine (e.g. -rw-rw-r--)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you install cygwin, you will get that in the bash shell.

Comment: You assume that Windows has a concept of file permissions that can be mapped to the traditional unix form "-rw-rw-r--". This is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the GNU Win32 tools.

It contains a lot of useful Linux/Unix tools for Windows.
That includes ls.
And unlike Cygwin, it's Windows native exe's. No need for cygwin.

See here: https://u-tools.com/msls.asp

And here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there anything with a GUI??

Comment: Thanks for that comment Stewart, just a quick question, when I use file zilla to transfer files I am able to get the file permissions in numbers (e.g. 777 ) is it possible to get file permissions for a NFS filesystem that's being shared by a linux system on windows using a GUI tool??